# Embbeded YouTube video not showing when admin logged in

Tags: youtube

Video not showing When admin logged in.
[image]

If Not logged in its shows.
[image]

Comment: I'd start by comparing the content on the page in both cases, and by checking the browser debug console for any errors. Is there anything else different about being logged in e.g. you're looking at an origin server URL in that case, etc.? How have you embedded these - just pasting the URL or as a standard block, or are you using a page builder or a plugin to embed the videos?

Comment: yes, elementor plugin video i pasted link, how to fix

Comment: I still think it's worth trying to debug yourself - compare the HTML on the page in both cases, look for errors in your browser console - but otherwise you should ask Elementor for help then.